# Getting error sudo:source: command not found on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, ruby

i need to install ruby version 2.1.5 and Rails version 4.2.0 on my Ubuntu server.Here  i am getting error which is given below.

Error:

```
sudo:source: command not
```

I followed the below steps for installing the ROR.

```
sudo apt-get install curl
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
sudo curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

but when i run this below command i got the above error.

```
sudo source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

Again if i am running below command

```
sudo rvm requirements
```

i am also getting the below error.

```
sudo:rvm:command not found
```

Please help me to resolve this error and install ROR environment.

Comment: Which shell are you working on?

Comment: @snoop : I am using putty/ssh to access my Ubuntu server machine and also i am accessing remotely from other machine.

Comment: Answered and tested.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Start**

   ```
   sudo -i gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
   ```

   *Sample output*

   ```
   gpg: directory `/root/.gnupg' created
   gpg: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
   gpg: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
   gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
   gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
   gpg: requesting key D39DC0E3 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
   gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
   gpg: key D39DC0E3: public key "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" imported
   gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
   gpg: Total number processed: 1
   gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
   ```

   and **NOT**

   ```
   sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
   ```
2. **Start**

   ```
   sudo -i sh -c "curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable"
   ```

   *Sample output*

   ```
   Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.26.11.tar.gz
   Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.26.11/1.26.11.tar.gz.asc
   gpg: Signature made Mo 30 Mär 2015 23:52:13 CEST using RSA key ID BF04FF17
   gpg: Good signature from "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>"
   gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
   gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
   Primary key fingerprint: 409B 6B17 96C2 7546 2A17  0311 3804 BB82 D39D C0E3
        Subkey fingerprint: 62C9 E5F4 DA30 0D94 AC36  166B E206 C29F BF04 FF17
   GPG verified '/usr/local/rvm/archives/rvm-1.26.11.tgz'
   Creating group 'rvm'

   Installing RVM to /usr/local/rvm/
   Installation of RVM in /usr/local/rvm/ is almost complete:

     * First you need to add all users that will be using rvm to 'rvm' group,
       and logout - login again, anyone using rvm will be operating with `umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx`.

     * To start using RVM you need to run `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`
       in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

   # aboettger,
   #
   #   Thank you for using RVM!
   #   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
   #
   # ~Wayne, Michal & team.

   In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io
   ```

   and **NOT**

   ```
   sudo curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
   ```
3. **Start**

   ```
   sudo bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"
   ```

   and **NOT**

   ```
   sudo source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
   ```
4. **Start**

   ```
   sudo -i rvm requirements
   ```

   *Sample output*

   ```
   Checking requirements for ubuntu.
   Installing requirements for ubuntu.
   Updating system.....................
   Installing required packages: libreadline6-dev, libyaml-dev, libsqlite3-dev, libgdbm-dev, libncurses5-dev, bison, libffi-dev........
   Requirements installation successful.
   ```

   and **NOT**

   ```
   sudo rvm requirements
   ```

Comment: @ A.B .what about the my second error.Check my post

Comment: i typed bash in ssh and retype your second command but still the error is there.

Comment: @satya Ok, please check your commands you've used and correct this in your question. It's important to have the correct syntax you've used to answer your question. eg 1) `sudo apt-get install curl.` the dot at the end is wrong. 2) `sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3.` same here. 3) `sudo \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable.` why the backslash?

Comment: I never used the dot at run time by i am still confused about the backslash.

Comment: @satya And include the output for each command, after you have started it, into your question.